# Cypress check that a string does not exist in body, excluding a block or div

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a series of strings to check that they don't exist in various pages; but I don't want to check a single div.

I have several pages where to check that strings "Miami", "Tampa" , "Naples", "Orlando" does NOT exist, but I have a `div` at the bottom of each page that contains

```
<div class="footer"><h3 class="availability">
                 We are also available in
            </h3> <a href="..." class="province">
                Miami
            </a><a href="..." class="province">
                Tampa
            </a><a href="..." class="province">
                Naples
            </a><a href="..." class="province">
                Orlando
            </a>
</div>
```

I created a test that loops in each page and checks that

```
cy.get('body').should('not.contain', 'Miami')
cy.get('body').should('not.contain', 'Tampa')
cy.get('body').should('not.contain', 'Naples')
cy.get('body').should('not.contain', 'Orlando')
```

But these test obviously fails because cypress find those strings in that `div`.

Is there a way to exclude it from search? I tried

```
cy.get('body')
    .not('footer')
    .should('not.contain', 'Miami')
```

But this doesn't work!

As a workaround, I thought i could remove the div from the dom, but I'm not sure if its a good idea and anyway I don't know how to do it in cypress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cy.get().not()` command is not seen very often, but the docs say

> Opposite of .filter()

which kind of means ***take all the elements found in `get()` and filter out any that match the `.not()`**.

So in

```js
cy.get('body')
  .not('.footer')                     // no class footer on body, no effect
  .should('not.contain', 'Miami')     // fails because not.contain is recursive
```

`body` does not have `.footer`, so nothing is filtered out.

And the next step `.should('not.contain'` searches all children of `body`, which includes `.footer`, and therefore fails the test.

If the footer is a **direct child** of `body`, you can add a `.children()` to make it work

```html
<body>
  <div>NYC</div>
  <div class="footer">Miami</footer>
</body>
```

```js
cy.get('body')
  .children()                        // direct descendants only
  .not('.footer')                    // now .footer is excluded
  .should('not.contain', 'Miami')    // passes
```

or using opposite logic

```js
cy.get('body')
  .find('.footer')
  .siblings()
  .should('not.contain', 'Miami')
```

If there is one or more levels between body and footer, you need to target the level correctly

```html
<body>
  <div class=""wrapper1">
    <div class=""wrapper2">
      <div>NYC</div>
      <div class="footer">Miami</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```js
cy.get('body')
  .children()                        // wrapper 1
  .children()                        // wrapper 2
  .children()
  .not('.footer')                    // .footer is excluded
  .should('not.contain', 'Miami')    // passes
```

but this starts to look messy, and is fragile if the structure changes.

The basic problem is that `.not()` is not recursive but `.should('not.contain', 'Miami')` is recursive. What would work is a non-recursive text checker.

This is the most robust way I could come up with

```js
cy.get('body')
  .find('*')                                    // children of body - recursive
  .not('.footer')                               // exclude the footer
  .each($el => {                   
    cy.wrap($el.contents().get(0).textContent)  // text of this element only (not children)
      .should('not.contain', 'Miami')           // passes
  })
```

where

```
$el.contents()     // list of element and all child nodes
   .get(0)         // filter just the parent
   .textContent    // get it's text
```

Comment: Thanks so much, man. I started using Cypress only a couple of weeks ago and I totally didn't know all these things. I learnt a lot, and plus this code works: I've just added a small check to avoid undefined in divs without text: `if ($el.contents().get(0)) {
                        cy.wrap($el.contents().get(0).textContent) 
                          .should('not.contain', 'Miami') }`
Modifing the code also gave me the chance to learn the behaviour of these selectors. Thanks!

Comment: p.s.: I used the `children()` version because the website is in vuejs, and using `.find('*')` caused a lot of checks in sub-menus :)

Comment: Just a small question more: if i have more than one block to exclude, can I chain the `.not()`? e.g. `.not('.footer').not('header')` ?

Comment: Yes, it works ok with multiple `.not()` to exclude different parts of the DOM.

Comment: And yes `.find('*') ` is a bit of a code smell. It is better practice to target more selectively, for a Vue app you may well have a `main` to target instead of `body`, which then excludes the auxiliary stuff like header, footer, menu.

Comment: thanks man, I really appreciate that. Before today this selector was a total mess in my mind

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue using `.not('footer')` comes from the fact that you are specifying it as a `div` with a class name of `footer`, instead of declaring a `footer` element. Correctly identifying the footer as `.footer` should resolve your issue.

```
cy.get('body')
    .not('.footer')
    .should('not.contain', 'Miami')
```

For simplicity, you could specify the `cy.get('body').not('.footer')` using the `as` command.

```
cy.get('body').not('.footer').as('bodyNoFooter');
cy.get('@bodyNoFooter').should('not.contain', 'Miami');
cy.get('@bodyNoFooter').should('not.contain', 'Orlando');
```

Comment: thanks for your help it was actually wrong but it's not working anyway; is there a way to `console.log` or to print in some way the excluded element (e.g. `bodynoFooter`)? Maybe I'm doing wrong something in selecting

Comment: Also, if I have other elements inside `footer`, are they exluded, too?